# SafeNet ProtectServer External 2 HSM

Tags: hsm, slots, hardware-security-module

I could not find the maximum number of slots that we can create on SafeNet ProtectServer External 2 hardware security module
If anyone know that please help!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into "ProtectToolkit C Administration Guide", section "The ProtectToolkit C Model", subsection "User Slots" for the answer...

Good luck!